# Keyboard default behaviour disabled using Slimbox2 / jCrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop, slimbox

Hey I'm using [Slimbox2](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2) in a Website but after opening up the lightbox effect the keyboard is useless.

What I mean is that the keyboard keys don't respond anymore. Like "F5" does not refresh the page and if I try and input text into some text fields I added dynamically, the text does not appear like normal.

Anyone else encountered this before?

It might also be [jCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) that causes this issue.

Anyway that I can prevent this behaviour and restore the normal behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of Slimbox. By default, only the `ESC`, `X` and `C` keys are enabled when a lightbox is open, these keys then close an open lightbox.

On the link in your OP look for the `closeKeys` parameter at the bottom of the page for a description this behaviour. You can provide this parameter an array of keycodes to allow.

Personally, that's an awful feature as it's very limiting for the user when a lightbox is open - especially disabling the F-keys. I'd use a different lightbox if you can.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree that that "feature" is not very well thought out. Isn't there a way to disable that feature? Otherwise I'd use another one. I think he should really implement a on/off setting for that "feature". :(

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way to disable the feature, other than supplying the `closeKeys` parameter with EVERY key-code, which is not a nice solution. It may be worth emailing the plugin creator with a request as that feature is very short-sighted.

Comment: Nah I went with another lightbox instead called [nyroModal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/)
Thanks for your help though :)